# Gravity forms - save form in user profile

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity

I have a multi step gravity form. I need to save it with a user profile. So whenever the user comes to the site, the form should be pre-filled from the entry made earlier by the user.

How can I achieve that?

I have tried it using - https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-sticky-form/ but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Gravity Forms User Registration Add-on](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/). It will allow you to save and update form data into the user meta (profile). As part of this, it will allow you to repopulate user meta back into the form.